# Variable body width

Tags: css

I have a simple HTML page with 3 "columns" (300px x 100%) that all have a vertical scrollbar. This works fine when having a window of at least 900 pixels in width. However, when I resize the window to be smaller than the columns take, one (or more) of the columns jump down to fit the window vertically. This is not what I want, because it would require the user to scroll all the way down before being able to see the other column.

What I want is pretty simple: a way to force the browser to fit the columns horizontally, even if it doesn't fit. `width: 900px;` on the body isn't a solution I want to use because the number of columns (and their width) is variable.

In other words: how do I force a browser to put my elements horizontally on a page and stop moving elements?

[edit]
My current code (well, it's not the actual code, but it does show what the problem is):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <style>
            * {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }

            body, html {
                height: 100%;
            }

            body {
                overflow-x: scroll;
            }

            .column {
                width: 300px;
                height: 100%;
                float: left;
                overflow-x: hidden;
                overflow-y: scroll;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
        <div class="column"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just for clarification, when you say force fit horizontally, you mean that the browser should show a horizontal scrollbar?

Comment: Yes. It's already there (`overflow-x: scroll`) but it doesn't actually put the columns horizontally on the page.

Comment: Could you give a sample tag of whats not working? Do you mean you want width in percentage instead of pixels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      * { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }

      body, html { height: 100%; }

      body { 
        overflow-x: scroll; 
        white-space: nowrap; // prevent 'text' from wrapping
      }

      .column {
        display:inline-block; // make them behave like 'text'
        width: 300px; height: 100%;

        overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: scroll;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
    <div class="column"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Does still mess with the columns a lot, but I'm sure that that can be fixed. :-)

Comment: make sure you set `white-space: normal;` for the columns. Otherwise your text will no longer wrap.

Answer (score 2):

The three "columns" need to be in a single container with the container's CSS set to 'nowrap'

```
<div style='white-space: nowrap;'>
  <div id='col1'></div>
  <div id='col2'></div>
  <div id='col3'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, this does not work. My text gets wrapped, but the elements do not.

Comment: Yes, this doesn't work with floats. But it got me on my way with my answer so **+1**

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there's no cross browser way to force semantic columns (without JavaScript).

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259957/css-auto-width-child-divs-in-parent-div/4261105#4261105) is the answer I gave to a similar question.

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">...</div>
  <div class="child">...</div>
  <div class="child">...</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.parent
{
  display: table-row;
}

.child
{
  display: table-cell;
  width: 300px;
}
```

I believe IE < 9 has issues with this, so you'll need to set the sizing and positioning manually with JS for IE.

Comment: Luckily this is a webkit-only problem so the cross-browser stuff is no problem. However, your solution does not seem to work. All it does is remove all scrollbars from the columns, but it doesn't put them next to each other.

Comment: Make sure you're not still floating the items.

Comment: If I stop floating the items, the columns resize. I'd like a scrollbar instead. :-)

Comment: you could try floating the `div.parent`.